# Graphing cos and transformations

Tags: trigonometry

I need to graph $y=-2\cos3x$

I just went the standard route and reflected across the x axis, multiplied the y axis by 2 and multiplied the x axis by three. Is this incorrect? I got the wrong answer but I am not sure why.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiplied the $x$-axis by three". Does that mean the waves became steeper or flatter (they should become steeper)? The first two steps sound good, though.

Comment: I mean that if it would normally cross the x axis at pi/2 it would then cross at 3pi/2  I think I just realized this is wrong and it should cross at pi/6 is that correct?

Comment: But then you shoud *divide* the $x$-axis by three. The point is that for $x = \pi/6$ you already have that $3x = 3\pi/6 = \pi/2$. "You run through the $x$ axis three times as fast as usual" due to the factor three: $1/3$ becomes $1$, $1$ becomes $3$, etc, when plugging into $3x$.

Comment: Yes! That's perfectly correct!

Comment: Yes, $-2\cos(3x)$ will cross the $x$-axis at $\pi/6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you said sounds correct, though Theo makes a good point that "multiplying the $x$-axis by 3" might be where your problem is. This is what you should be seeing at each step:
[image]

Comment: Would it be correct to say that the 3x part makes the period occur at a smaller interval? So basically to find the period I would take 2pi/3? That should be the new period, every 120 degrees?

Comment: @Adam: Absolutely correct!

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens when you solve the equation for $x$. You get $x=\frac{1}{3}\ldots$, not $x=3\ldots$. Thus, whatever you mean by "multiplying an axis by a factor", your two multiplications can't both be right, since what corresponds to the factor $2$ for $y$ is a factor of $\frac{1}{3}$ for $x$, not $3$. (Alternatively, you can divide by $2$ to see that what corresponds to the factor of $3$ for $x$ is a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ for $y$, not $2$.)